# Div should appear when user scrolls down and back up again, but not on load

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm a complete novice at javascript so this will probably be really easy for you.My website (http://www.pjsmusic.com) requires a div of 200px when the user scrolls 40px down the page to appear. I have added some javascript

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $('#jerkBox').toggle($(this).scrollTop()> 40);
});
```

However, the div appears when the page loads even as the page isn't scrolled from the top at all. How could I make this div appear when the user scrolls 40px, and disappear when they scroll back up the page past 40px, but not appear on load? You'll see what I mean if you visitthe link. Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle? as at present it is hard to understand what you're asking

Comment: Not really, there are lots of external scripts on the website. Se the website linked, and the whitespace at the top that disappears when you scroll down is the problem.

Comment: The jerkBox element is the one with the "Search pjs music..." input ??

Comment: I mean the question is what do you want to show/hide when scrolling ?

Comment: Haha those guys below have solved it :) Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery `.toggle()` controls the `display` property of the element. You can set it as `display: none` on the css right from the start:

```
#jerkBox {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $('#jerkBox').toggle($(this).scrollTop()> 40);
});
```

```css
#jerkBox {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jerkBox">
    jerkBox div
</div>
<div style="height: 2000px">
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct answer! Didn't realise it would be so simple! Cheers mate

Comment: @TobyFox, No problem.. Glad to help! :)  - if it fit your needs please mark as the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to hide `#jerkBox` by default.  Either in the CSS style of the element, set it to `display: none` or hide it immediately on document ready in your script.

```
/* CSS */
#jerkBox {
  display: none;
}
```

or

```
/* JavaScript */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#jerkBox').hide();
}
```

Comment: Setting it by JS wouldn't be a good idea because pc running slow would make it blink

Comment: Thanks so much. I've set it in CSS, didn't realise it would be so simple to fix. I appreciate it guys. :)